# String "10" vs string "100"

Tags: java, string, split, switch-statement, case

If I am using switch statements to run different methods depending on a cash amount, how would I differentiate between the $100 string and the $10 string.

I have tried doing "$10 " with a space after the 10, but given the nature of the program/project, the string must stay "$10"

```
case "$100":
    Information.displayHundreds();
case "$50":
    Information.displayFifties();
case "20":
    Information.displayTwenties();
case "10":
    Information.displayTens();
```

### Here is the original problem given to me (I am working on I):

You are to write a command-line cash machine (ATM).
The cash machine is pre-stocked with the following denominations:

$100 - 10 Bills

$50 - 10 Bills
$20 - 10 Bills

$10 - 10 Bills

$5 - 10 Bills

$1 - 10 Bills

Your application should take input from the standard input stream and support the following commands:

R - Restocks the cash machine to the original pre-stock levels defined above

W   - Withdraws that amount from the cash machine (e.g. "W $145")

I   - Displays the number of bills in that denomination present in the cash machine (e.g. I $20 $10 $1)

Q - Quits the application

The withdrawals from the cash machine should dispense cash in the most efficient manner possible, with the least amount of bills.  After a withdrawal, the program should display success or failure and the remaining balance in the cash machine (sample output below).  For an inquiry, the program should display the number of bills in the denominations specified (sample output below).  After a restock, the program should display the balance in the cash machine (same as after a withdrawal).  If the input is not understood, "Invalid Command" should be displayed.  No additional messages, prompts or errors should be displayed.

Comment: Hey! IMO it's absolutely unclear what the problem is. Could you rephrase it? Especially *"I have tried doing "$10 " but given the nature of the program/project, it needs to exclusively stay "$10""*.

Comment: Why do you need to differentiate between `$100` and `$10`, could you provide more details.

Comment: The switch statement will know which case to process.  As long as the cases are unique, you should not have to actively differentiate anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
case "$100": 
   System.out.println("Information.displayHundreds");
case "100":
   System.out.println("Information.displayHundreds");
```

maybe use  if else is  better , because switch case need clear value

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the $ symbol and convert to a number. That way, things will be easier for you (less complex) to compare.
Afterwards, you can add back the $ symbol and even keep track of if it was there in the beginning.

Comment: Define easy in the context of a switch statement.  And your "answer" is a guess so it should he a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Can use replace or split remove "$" first ?

```
public class xxxx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String money = "$50";

        String m = money.replace("$","");

        switch(m){
            case "$100":
                System.out.println("Information.displayHundreds");
            case "50":
                System.out.println("Information.displayFifties");
            case "20":
                System.out.println("Information.displayTwenties");
            case "10":
                System.out.println("Information.displayTens");
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there's a typo in the 1st case: $100 will not ever be found
because $ was removed

Comment: you can use 

case "$100": 
   System.out.println("Information.displayHundreds");
case "100":
   System.out.println("Information.displayHundreds");

maybe use  if else is  better , because switch case need clear value